# How could i access [object Object] in EJS?

Tags: ejs

I'm uploading multiple images with multer by `upload.any()` and passing the `req.files` to `imgdet`, then I got `[object Object]`.
I need to display all the images.

This is my console result:

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

This 4 objects represent 4 images.

My code:

```
<span class="product-border">   
   <% var itm = JSON.stringify(item[i].imgdet); %>     
   <% console.log(itm); %>     
   <img src="/uploads/<%= item[i].imgdet %>" alt="">                                                
</span>
```

this is what one item contain

```
[ { _id: 5c4f09b9fcb8c325cc5cdf5a,
    product:
     { _id: 5c4f08168af248297c60c807,
       category: 5c3f360b70ea8f0f8c6bc558,
       productname: '8',
       image: 'oneimg-1548683286064.jpg',
       __v: 0 },
    code: '888',
    thkns: '888',
    dimension: '888',
    volume: '888',
    lining: '888',
    weight: '888',
    text: '888',
    imgdet:
     '[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]',
    __v: 0 } ]
```

Comment: So. You want to see the preview of these images. Right? Or just logging information about images' Object

Comment: `itm` seem to be an array. I think you can iterate using for https://pugjs.org/language/code.html

Comment: 陈杨华  I need to display it as product details images, and it will be slider

Comment: Sridhar I will try

Comment: @陈杨华 i put what one item contain maybe could be helpful

Comment: Got it. I'm the same as Sridhar. so you can use "for loop" in EJS

Comment: 陈杨华 did you see the extra code i added already !? but when i'm looping still i get object. maybe i need something like JSON.stringify but it's not stringify it at all

Comment: i guess i have to extract the object to got the key value from it right !?

Comment: try to render `item` in your controller this way `JSON.stringify(item)` and in your ejs access it with `JSON.parse(item)`

Comment: dimitris tseggenes perfect man, it's worked. it's worked man thank you very much you made my day and it was right solution and you did it without any more details  for my code. you are the best :) then how can i mark your answer the right one ?

Answer (score 0):

First of that's an array, and to access each element you need to iterate through it. The simplest iterator is a for of loop so you can use that here.

```js
for (const itm of item) {
  console.log(itm)
}
```